# Topological SLAM algorithm?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just wondering, if there exists any algorithm that builds a map in a topological way (based on landmarks) instead of in a metric way (x,y).  Since the gyro/odom has error anyway, it is not necessary to build a metric map. Even humans will not do this. We recognize landmarks to estimate our location, right? Is anyone aware of this kind of research?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60261/topological-slam-algorithm?/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a number of topological SLAM implementations in the research community. http://openslam.org/ is a good source for finding these.

Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, none of these have ROS bindings/wrappers available.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dr Paul Newman and Mark Cummins released an open source version of Fast Appearance Based Mapping (FABMAP) toolset that`s a topological SLAM algorithm

You should have a look at this reference too:

R. Kuemmerle, B. Steder, C. Dornhege, A. Kleiner, G. Grisetti, and W. Burgard.
Large Scale Graph-based SLAM using Aerial Images as Prior Information

I hope I`ve helped you

---

Originally posted by [ClaudioS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4644/claudios/) with karma: 21 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1